# AccessToken is not valid error : iOS Obj C

Tags: objective-c, rest, authorization

I am developing an iOS application in objective C where when a user logins to the App, it will return an access token in son format. I need to query other server api with the access token. My son response is like :

```
{
    accessToken = "$2a$10$6Tu7e.fsKQxp4cw/SkRBS.65wsA.Pagt2EwdpBjXRdaUQb6yNxTtS";
    id = 12;
    message = "login successful";
    success = 1;
}
```

I am retrieving this via

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
[jsonDict valueForKey:@"accessToken"];
```

Whenever i try with the accessToken get from this, it shows invalid access token.(I use the same access token in postman.and got the same response).

When I copy the access token from postman and use the same in iOs code, it works fine. What is happening? Any help will be appreciated. 
The code I am using to call the http request is:

```
  //  NSString *accessToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"accessToken"];

    //Send JSON data to cloud using HTTP POST
    NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request1 = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url1
                                                            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    [request1 setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
   // [request1 setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request1 setValue:accessToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    NSLog(@"access :: %@",accessToken);
    NSURLConnection *conn1 = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request1 delegate:self];
```

Comment: I would guess that you need to normalize this string.. because it has this special symbols.. [accessToken stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:NSUTF8StringEncoding]

Comment: not working.. got an error like implicit conversion of int to nscharacterset is disallowed in arc

Comment: I tried with NSDictionary *access = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"$2a$10$KEO2vbG9TkV2bZCAPX94QOZUp4QKcfXhkAQGddLqzgwFSPkVc42pS",@"test", nil]; . Then it works. So in my thinking something is happened in json serialisation. Is it correct?

Comment: I have tried something as shown and it worked : NSString *aces1 = @"$2a$10$yx3Dybh6hVmRaAeZvZMh0ebQE/Olkp.rWOSiVRKL3fHcTnSHeYJT6";
        NSLog(@" aces1 %@ ::", aces1);
        NSDictionary *access = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:aces1,@"test", nil];
        NSData *data1 = [self createJSON:access];
        NSDictionary *accessDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data1 options:0 error:nil];
         NSString *accessToken = [accessDict valueForKey:@"test"];                        with a valid token got from postman. What is the problem? really troubling me. pls help